# Can lombok generate builder based on the type solely?

Tags: java, lombok

I have a use case where ***I don't want to use the @Builder on the class itself***, so I created method based builder like this:

```
  @Builder(builderMethodName = "carBuilder")
  public static Car build(int speed, String brand){
    Car car = new Car();
    car.setSpeed(speed);
    car.setBrand(brand);
    return car;
  }
```

But how can I handle when the given class has ton of fields (over ~20).
Should I really specify them as parameters and invoke the setters by hand?
Couldn't just lombok generate them automatically based on the type?

Answer (score 2):

Currently this is not possible because Lombok avoids inspecting types from elsewhere on the classpath when processing a file.

What's your reason for not adding `@Builder` to the class itself? If you can describe a common use case for that, you or someone else **might** be able to add this ability to Lombok. However, currently I can't see any good reasons for this. Most libraries should be relatively easy to use already and if its your own code, why not just add Lombok?

Also the main reason I add `@Builder` is because I want my classes to be immutable - given that the actual object is still mutable here, why use builder rather than the setters?

Comment: I have to write tests for an existing code base without touching the code.
Using only setters can make sense thanks.

Comment: @beatrice Additionally, you can use `@Accessors(fluent=true, chained=true)` for builder-like setter chaining.

Comment: @maaartinus I don't think that will help - beatrice is wanting to generate code without touching the class in question.

Comment: @mjaggard Right.... but there's an equivalent setting using `lombok.config` (see the link in the Javadoc of `lombok.Accessors`). It works for the whole package, which may or may not be wanted.

Comment: @maaartinus I think beatrice mentioned that they don't want to touch to code, only the tests - so I'm assuming that wouldn't work.